# QGridLayout para disponer los elementos en la parte superior de la pantalla

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qgridlayout

Estoy utilizando QGridLayout en Pyqt5 para maquetar una ventana en python. Lo que quiero hacer es que los elementos no se dispongan para ocupar todo el ancho y alto de la ventana, si no que se agrupen en la zona superior de la ventana. Mi código es:

```
def __init__(self, fileInfo, parent=None):
    super(tabBuscadorProductos, self).__init__(parent)

    #Fichero de configuracion
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('properties.conf')

    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 131, 16))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label.setText("Criterio de busqueda:")

    self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 121, 22))
    self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
    list = config.get('COMBO_CRITERIOS', 'productos').split(" ")
    self.comboBox.addItems(list)

    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 40, 121, 16))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.label_2.setText("Producto:")

    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 40, 271, 22))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 55, 16))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.label_3.setText("Local: ")

    self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
    self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 80, 121, 22))
    self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
#         locales = config.get('COMBO_EMPRESAS', 'empresas')
    self.comboBox_2.addItems(obtenerLocales())

    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 130, 93, 28))


    icon = QtGui.QIcon()
    icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd()+"\\images\\lupa2.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)

    self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton.setText("Buscar")
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buscar)

    self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
    self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 211, 20))
    self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
    self.checkBox.setText("Incluir productos con stock a 0")

    mainLayout = QGridLayout()
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 4, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 5, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 5, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(3, 1)
    mainLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
    mainLayout.setRowStretch(3, 1)

   # mainLayout.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

Y lo quiero obtener es esto (la tabla todavía no está implementada):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sencilla es colocar un QVBoxLayout al widget, y en ese widget colocar el QGridLayout, y despues añadir el stretch con addStretch():

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        vboxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setText("Criterio de busqueda:")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_2.setText("Producto:")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_3.setText("Local: ")

        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setText("Buscar")

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.checkBox.setText("Incluir productos con stock a 0")

        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 5, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 5, 1, 1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        vboxLayout.addLayout(mainLayout)
        vboxLayout.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Una cosa, sabrías como puedo hacer el botón de "Buscar" más pequeño sin que ello afecte al QLineEdit de "Producto"?

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 voy a buscar alguna forma, pero por otro lado `setGeometry(...)` no tiene sentido si se va a usar un layout

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 una solución es establecer un tamaño fijo al QPushButton:  `self.pushButton.setFixedSize(100, 30)`

Comment: ok, así funciona perfectamente :) lo malo es que ahora tengo que ver como alinearlo a la derecha para que no se quede en el medio

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 ¿se te centra?, en mi caso se alinea al lado izquierdo.

Comment: @Adriana_0_0 si quieres que este a la derecha debes usar: `mainLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 5, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)`

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias :)